# Display output of vgg19 layer as image

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I was reading this paper: [Neural Style Transfer](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.06576.pdf). In this paper author reconstructs image from output of layers of vgg19. I am using Keras. The size of output of `block1_conv1` layer is `(1, 400, 533, 64)`. Here 1 is number of images as input, 400 is number of rows, 533 number of columns and 64 number of channels. When I try to reconstruct it as an image, I get an error as size of image is 13644800 which is not a multiple of 3, so I can't display the image in three channels. How can I reconstruct this image?

I want to reconstruct images from layers as shown below:
[image: image reconstruction from vgg layers]
Below is the code for the same:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from scipy.misc import imsave
import numpy as np
from keras.applications import vgg19
from keras import backend as K

CONTENT_IMAGE_FN = store image as input here

def preprocess_image(image_path):
    img = load_img(image_path, target_size=(img_nrows, img_ncols))
    img = img_to_array(img)
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    img = vgg19.preprocess_input(img)
    return img

width, height = load_img(CONTENT_IMAGE_FN).size
img_nrows = 400
img_ncols = int(width * img_nrows / height)
base_image = K.variable(preprocess_image(CONTENT_IMAGE_FN))

RESULT_DIR = "generated/"
RESULT_PREFIX = RESULT_DIR + "gen"
if not os.path.exists(RESULT_DIR):
  os.makedirs(RESULT_DIR)
result_prefix = RESULT_PREFIX

# this will contain our generated image
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    combination_image = K.placeholder((1, 3, img_nrows, img_ncols))
else:
    combination_image = K.placeholder((1, img_nrows, img_ncols, 3))

x = preprocess_image(CONTENT_IMAGE_FN)

outputs_dict = dict([(layer.name, layer.output) for layer in model.layers])
feature_layers = ['block1_conv1', 'block2_conv1',
                  'block3_conv1', 'block4_conv1',
                  'block5_conv1']
outputs = []
for layer_name in feature_layers:
  outputs.append(outputs_dict[layer_name])
functor = K.function([combination_image], outputs )   # evaluation function

# Testing
test = x
layer_outs = functor([test])
print(layer_outs)

layer_outs[0].reshape(400, -1 , 3) //getting error here
```

I am getting following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 13644800 into shape (400,newaxis,3)
```

Comment: much more information and codes, please if you need help

Comment: added code and more information

Comment: It is wise if you add the full original error message in this case.

Comment: @AbhayGupta I am also working on NST and facing the same error as you. If you found the solution, can you please tell me?

Answer (score 0):

**You wrote:**

> "The size of output of `block1_conv1` layer is `(1, 400, 533, 64`). Here 1
>   is number of images as input, 400 is number of rows, 533 number of
>   columns and 64 number of channels"
>   But this is not correct. The `block1_conv1` output corresponds 1 channel dimension(channel first), 400 * 533 image dimension and 64 **filters**.

The error occurs, as you try to reshape a vector of `VGG19` output of an image input with a 1 channel **(400 * 533 * 64 = 13644800)** to a vector which correspond to a 3 channels output.

Furthermore you have to pass **3 channel** input:

From the **VGG19** code:

> **input_shape:** optional shape tuple, only to be specified
>               if `include_top` is False (otherwise the input shape
>               has to be `(224, 224, 3)`
>               (with `channels_last` data format)
>               or `(3, 224, 224)` (with `channels_first` data format).
>               It should have exactly 3 inputs channels,
>               and width and height should be no smaller than 32.
>               E.g. `(200, 200, 3)` would be one valid value.

Thus your input images has to be 3 channels. If you even want to feed 1 channel(grayscale) images to `VGG19` you should make the following, if `channels first`:

```
X = np.repeat(X, 3 , axis=0)
```

or

```
X = np.repeat(X, 3 , axis=2)
```

if `channels last` **without batch dimension** or

```
X = np.repeat(X, 3 , axis=3)
```

**with batch dimension**.

If you provide more information regarding the actual dimensions of your input matrices of your images and type of it(grayscale,RGB), I can give you more help upon needing it.

Comment: You misunderstood the size. 1 is the batch size, not number of channels. Number of channels is 64. I want to convert it into a 3 channel RGB image. I guess the question was not clear. I have also updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @AbhayGupta No, 64 is the number of **filters**. Anyway I study your updated question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19, preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

# Load and preprocess the image
img_path = 'path_to_your_image.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

# Load the pre-trained VGG19 model
model = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# Specify the layer for visualization
layer_name = 'block4_conv1'

# Extract the output of the desired layer
layer_output = model.get_layer(layer_name).output

# Create a model that outputs the layer's activations
activation_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=layer_output)

# Get the activations for the input image
activations = activation_model.predict(x)

# Display each channel as a separate image
num_channels = activations.shape[-1]
rows = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(num_channels)))
cols = int(np.ceil(num_channels / rows))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(10, 10))

for channel, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    if channel < num_channels:
        ax.imshow(activations[0, :, :, channel], cmap='viridis')
        ax.axis('off')
    else:
        ax.axis('off')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76265312/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).